# Why is specific heat measured in J/kg °C?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the equation c = Q/mΔT, why is ΔT written in celsius? I thought Kelvin was the universal unit of temperature in physics.

Comment: Do you know what the conversion factor is to convert $\Delta T$ in Celsius to $\Delta T$ in Kelvin?

Comment: *why is ΔT written in celsius?* Written *where*? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) uses kelvins in the units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if $\Delta T$ is in Celsius or Kelvin. One degree Celsius is the same as one degree Kelvin. In other words, the magnitude of a degree Celsius is the same as the magnitude of a degree Kelvin. So you can use either Celsius or Kelvin in your equation or any equation where $\Delta T$ is involved.

What is different is 0 deg Celsius equals 273.1 Deg Kelvin. So if an equation involves T (as opposed to $\Delta T$) in absolute degrees, you must use Kelvin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation is a change in temperature, $\Delta T$, and since a change of temperature of $1\,\rm K$ is the same as a change of temperature of $1^\circ\rm C$ either unit can be used.
The use of the degree Celsius continues because of its familiarity with the public when used in very many fields eg weather forecasting, cooking, etc and the fact that so many thermometers and appliances with temperature scales that are calibrated in degree Celsius (originally degree centigrade) exist.